# How does voltage sensitive dyes actually determine neural network in foetus?

Tags: optics

In research topics of neurophotonics, the best way of determination of neural network in foetus is by using voltage-sensitive dyes instead of placing diodes. But how does it actually work? Sorry if the answer is too much  descriptive, so any link or short point type answers are also welcome.

Comment: That's a question for biology, not physics.

Comment: Sorry but it comes under neurophotonics. It is definitely the conjunction of photonics and neurology and has Spie recognition for being a subject of optics

Comment: SPIE is a technical organization and it doesn't define what belongs into physics proper. If you have a question about physical principles, e.g. how fluorescence works (including voltage sensitive dyes), then you might expect to get good answers. How to use fluorescent dyes in a biological application, that's a question for biologists.

Comment: I didn't ask how to use it. I asked for principles or mechanism upon which it works. I guess that comes under physics. And actually there is no particular area for neurophotonics. So had to post it here.

Comment: Your question clearly asks how these dyes determine neural networks in a foetus, which is a biological question (the closes a physicist ever comes to those things is by having an egg in the morning). I think a better question would have been "How do voltage sensitive dyes work?" without any reference to biology. Is that what you want to know?

Comment: Yeah. I want to know that.

Comment: If I understand it correctly, there are two necessary pieces to the function of these dyes. For one thing the optically active part of the dye molecule has to be aligned in the electric field inside a membrane of a neural cell, for another the electronic states of the molecule have to be changed by the electric field it is in. The latter is believed to be a direct physical mechanism rather than a chemical change induced by the environment. I would have to see some serious physical evidence for that, although I wouldn't rule it out by a naive argument like electric field strength.

Comment: Hmm. Okay, good logic.

Comment: At closer look, there are several different technologies and physical principles in use. Life Technologies, for instance, has a two piece technology, which is probably more sensitive (but much slower) than directly field sensitive molecules: http://www.lifetechnologies.com/us/en/home/life-science/drug-discovery/target-and-lead-identification-and-validation/ion-channel-biology/icb-misc/voltage-sensor-probes/mechanism-of-voltage-sensor-probe-technology-and-vsp-applications.html